# Who or what do the “among others” refer to in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Below is a quote from the book I read recently.

> George Bush's victory in the 2000 presidential election was an
> extremely narrow one, with a controversy over who won Florida's
> electoral votes, ***among others***.

Who or what do you think the "among others" refer to in this context?

Comment: ... among other controversies.

Comment: In that case, I just wonder whether we should put the comma right before "*among others*"? Since the phrase "*with a controversy over who won Florida's electoral votes*" is written parenthetically, I thought that "*among others*" was linked with the part coming before the first comma.

Comment: It is ambiguous. It should ideally be a) with a controversy, among other things, over who won Florida's electoral votes. or b) with a controversy over who among others, won Florida's electoral votes.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear and ambiguous, unless the reader already understands the detailed context. Other controversies, other winners, other states, or other votes?

The historical context is that the emphasis is on other controversies (rather than states, winners or votes) surrounding these events. That being so, the sentence would have been better written as “... with, among other controversies, one over ...”

Comment: I thought that other controversies/states/votes were at least highly unlikely because of the unnecessary comma after "votes".

Comment: Agreed. But “highly unlikely” still leaves a small residue of ambiguity, as recognised by the poster of the question, by you and by me :)

Comment: @Takashi-- If you "thought that other controversies/states/votes were at least highly unlikely", what according to you is " among others" possibly hinting at? And the comma before "among others"/after " votes" is not at all unnecessary. Rather, it is the one placed after "narrow one" that makes you think that the whole phrase is a parenthetical one (which it isn't for then we would have a meaningless sentence), and needs to be replaced with another punctuation mark--- an em dash, preferably.

Comment: @Stockfish  "*what according to you is "among others" possibly hinting at?*" That's the part I can't figure out by myself, and that's why I'm interested in knowing how native or near-native English speakers read the sentence. If "among others" refers to "other controversies/states/votes", then why do we need to separate "among others" from "with.......votes" phrase? Isn't there any possibility, do you think, that "among others" would be suggesting "among other victories in the past presidential election"?

Comment: I agree there is confusion. The sentence, as it stands, is ambiguous and any number of interpretations are possible. I think Edwin Ashworth has pretty much nailed it-- the qualifier "among other" or a variant should be placed more judiciously.

Answer (score 0):

To render the meaning clear while keeping the phrase "with a controversy over who won Florida's electoral votes" an essential part of the sentence (which I'm sure the writer intended to) calls for an em dash, instead of a comma.

Comment: Agreed. A good alternative.

Comment: I'd say the punctuation issue is secondary. The qualifier _among others_ or a variant should be placed more judiciously. '... with a controversy (among various others) over who won Florida's electoral votes.' // ' ... with a controversy over who won Florida's (among other states') electoral votes.' // ' ... with a controversy over who won Florida's electoral (among other) votes.'