# Use of no comma in independent clauses

Tags: commas

Are the following sentences are correct?

1. Tim is a manufacturer and he is not able to fix the car.
2. Tim is a manufacturer, and he is not able to fix the car.

I think the first sentence is wrong because it doesn't have the **comma** before AND, since they both can be independent sentences. Am I correct?

I have taken the first sentence from an App (BBC English Learning - Playstore)

Answer (score 0):

Placing a comma before  a coordinating conjunction is a matter of style; both your sentences are correct for this reason.

However, because comma suggests a pause, the second sentence, unlike the first, forces the revelation of Tim's not being able to fix 'the car' upon the reader.

Comment: Yes, I'd not use (1) here ... it seems implausibly bland. But I'd choose 'Tim is a _manufacturer_ and he is not able to fix the car!' or even '_Tim is a manufacturer_ and he is not able to fix the car!'

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: There is this pending question about punctuation (Who or what do the “among others” refer to in the context?)-- Mind going over to settle it? :)

Comment: @Stockfish: Link?

Comment: @ Peter Mortensen https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/544645/who-or-what-do-the-among-others-refer-to-in-the-context

Comment: One or two answers (one by this writer) have been provided, but I am not sure if they could be considered definitive.